# OneSignal creating multiple user records for each app installation

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, onesignal

I shifted from **parse.com** to **oneSignal** for push notification service.
I integrated the SDK into my android app and it is able to create **a user record** in oneSignal, when the application is installed.
But when I uninstall and re-install my android app, a new user record is created in oneSignal, resulting in duplicate user records.

How do I over come this issue of duplication? I want only one user record even if the user reinstalls my application.

In parse.com I use to check at the parse cloud code for duplicates before inserting new records .. any thing similar at oneSignal ?

Comment: Currently sitting here with the same problem as you, curious over what u ended up doing?

Comment: @mattias Sorry for the late reply. I went ahead with OneSignal. I wrote code on my server side to 'activate' or deactivate' records based on a unique tag but unfortunately I cannot delete them yet.

Comment: Ah okay, did something similar, thanks. Doesn't seem like they want to add the choice to delete them from the api, atleast not for now.

Comment: @mattias You should pitch the idea for sure. "Gdeglin" is the CEO of OneSignal (the answer below) and I did request him for the same. Maybe you can request it too as this is a basic requirement in push frameworks.

Answer (score 3):

OneSignal's SDK does its best to try to prevent duplicate user records from being created. This is mainly done by checking the users' Advertising Identifier, basically a unique ID that remains the same between different times the application is installed.

However, some Android users have opted-out of allowing apps to see their Advertising ID. In these cases it is not possible for OneSignal to know that a user has re-installed the app, and a duplicate user record will be created.

When OneSignal next attempts to send a notification to the previous user record, Google's GCM servers notify OneSignal's system that the user has a newer push token. At this point OneSignal will then disable the old user record so that future notifications are not sent to it. OneSignal's SDK will also make sure not to ever display the same notification twice on a device.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But using google ad ID for the "uniqueness" of a user is a bit tricky..right? Firstly - Some users opt out of it, secondly - Users change their devices quite frequently.
 The closest possibility,I see, of over coming this issue is allowing an API to delete users, which is currently missing. Or can you kindly suggest a better solution ?

Answer (score 2):

you have to do it this way before you create a new user check if the the user is already present using this api `idsAvailable` in android
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-native-sdk
and the same one for server can be found here
https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference

Comment: The OneSignal's init code in the android's application class creates the user record, way before my code is initialised for checks. 
I can check existing users for duplicates later on, but I cannot delete user records using the SDK or API .. or can I ?

Comment: in your application before you call init run this api call

Comment: This is wrong or you didn't get my problem. I cannot execute any code to oneSignal servers unless the init() is called. (API , keys registration etc happens) .
Moreover to check if duplicate user exists, I have to login the user to my servers, which definitely doesn't happen in the Android's application class( init() goes in the Application class ).